# Trying to compile powertop for arm using cross compile in Ubuntu with malloc issue

Tags: compiling, arm, powertop, cross-compilation

I have been trying to compile powertop for an arm device.  I saw powertop talked about here quite a bit and I am using Ubuntu to cross compile for the `armv7l`.

The configure goes through checking and produces:

```
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... no
checking for working strtod... no
checking for pow... yes
```

It gets to the devlist.cpp and dies because of the malloc not being there.

```
...
CXX      cpu/powertop-intel_cpus.o
CXX      powertop-devlist.o
devlist.cpp: In function ‘void collect_open_devices()’:
devlist.cpp:147: error: ‘rpl_malloc’ was not declared in this scope
devlist.cpp: In function ‘void register_devpower(const char*, double, device*)’:
devlist.cpp:249: error: ‘rpl_malloc’ was not declared in this scope
make[3]: *** [powertop-devlist.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lucid/powertop-2.4/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
...
```

If I make it skip the devlist.cpp then I get other memory function issues just like above.

I guess my question is how might I change the configuration or make to use the malloc correctly?  Do I need to build another library?  My toolchain should have every thing I need.

I call configure and make like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/lucid/timesys/i_MX53start/toolchain --sysconfdir=/home/lucid/timesys/i_MX53start/toolchain/etc --disable-static --target=armv7l-timesys-linux --host=i686 --build=armv7l-timesys-linux && make
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set some environment variables to run from your toolchain.  An example I use below, for a toolchain installed in my local directory, like yours:

```
MY_ARM_BASE=${HOME}/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3
C_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include:${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include-fixed
LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib:${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2
#OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
COMPILER_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/bin
#LD_RUN_PATH
#GPROF_PATH
#######
CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc
CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++
RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib
STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip
export C_INCLUDE_PATH LIBRARY_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH
export CC CXX RANLIB STRIP
```

Comment: I did have most of what you point out here but I may have missed a couple of include paths.  I am trying it now.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat correct so +1.  I was missing some declarations for the includes that I found later after finding the following link: [configure and malloc](http://nerdland.net/unstumping-the-internet/malloc-has-not-been-declared/)  Though the problem actually comes from the configure.ac.  They have added 2 memory checks that cause me my trouble.  If I modify the config.h to remove the `#define`s that change `malloc` to `rpl_malloc`, that is generated it does seem to fix my problem stated above.  The same with `rpl_realloc`.